# samba: why mode of mounted file changed?

Tags: samba, samba4

The mode of file on server is "644" but when I access through the mount, the mode is "755". I want to keep mode the same. Both server and client are ubuntu system.

This is the smb.conf.

```
[shared]
  comment = shared directory
  path = /share
  browsable = yes
  valid users = user
  read only = no
  writable = yes
  force user = user
  guest ok = yes
  available = yes
  browsable = yes
  public = yes
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
```

This is the line from /etc/fstab.

```
//server/shared /mnt/shared  cifs  username=user,password=...,uid=...,gid=... 0 0
```

Try the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958888/preserving-file-permissions-for-samba-shares-when-file-is-edited

But doesn't seem to work, :(

Comment: Use NFS.  You are adding a layer of complexity, that is not needed here. UNIX permissions do not translate perfectly to Windows permissions, or vise versa.